# SARS-CoV - relative size of the spike protein

Tags: biochemistry, molecules, chemical-biology, proteins, molecular-dynamics

I am taking an online course in image analysis and have been asked to use the attached image to determine the size of the SARS-S protein of the SARS-CoV relative to the total of its proteins. However, I have been given no explanation of the image, and with a physics background, I simply do not understand it. Can someone please explain the image (specifically the SARS-CoV column).

[image]

Comment: Biology is more suitable for this, I think.

Comment: @orthocresol, I tried but they said that they don't help with homework (although I am not asking you to solve the problem - simply to help me understanding the image).

Comment: Hmm. This is a tough case. After all, Chem.SE has a similar 'homework" policy; and although I can understand your point, it may or may not be that other users will be sympathetic towards it. I think it could also logically be closed as being off-topic (i.e. not about chemistry). To be entirely honest, the root cause of the problem is that you're given an image without any context whatsoever, and asked to interpret it. That seems like an unrealistic expectation to me, and even though you may happen to find an answer on SE, it seems to me that that'd only be a one-time, superficial fix.

Comment: It's been a long time since I did biology, but I think I can at least point you in the direction of the [Western blot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_blot) and [gel electrophoresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gel_electrophoresis_of_proteins). Wikipedia might not be the best resource on this. You might be able to find other easier explanations elsewhere on the Internet.

Comment: The Western blot looks similar to the image, so I will try and read about that. Thank you for trying to help, @orthocresol.

Comment: Measure how far over the background the first band in lane 8 is, and divide it by how far over the background all signal in lane 8 is.

Comment: @KarstenTheis, when you say 'the first band' in lane 8, do you mean the black line in the top at the SARS-S row?

Comment: Yes, the one at the same height as the main bond in the SARS-S lane.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although this is a homework question, I also think OP deserves a help as orthocresol suggested. I'm not going to go into details but leave it at orthocresol's suggestion of this being a Western Blot of protein analysis, which is absolutely correct. Hence, OP should start reading of electrophoresis and western blots techniques since, I assume, s/he taking molecular biology class.

In brief, the given image is a X-ray photograph of the nitrocellulose membrane after transferring the proteins from the SDS-PAGE gel (after electrophoresis). I'm suggesting that because the image looks like visualized by radioactivity (I suggest OP to read about these techniques in details to understand). In SDS-PAGE gel electrophoresis, the proteins separated mainly by molar mass of each protein while heaviest protein go first since electric current run from top to bottom as sepicted in following diagram:

[image: SARS-CoV-2]

As marked in the diagram, SARS-CoV consists of SARS-M ($\pu{20 kD}$, SARS-N ($\pu{54 kD}$, and SARS-S (~$\pu{175 kD}$ proteins. I may give you your answer but I strongly suggest to read about the subject for better understanding. I do not support online courses, but there are no choice you can made during a bad pandemic era.

Comment: I am not taking a class in molecular biology; it is supposed to be a class in image analysis with a focus on using the software, not understanding biology (we have also analyzed pictures of faces, traffic, etc.). It is online because the university is shot down. 
You say SARS-CoV consists of the three proteins you indicated with a red line, but what are all the small lines in between?

Comment: Those are some other proteins, of which authors either didn't understand or have no interest. SARS-ME have identical or similar proteins with different concentrations. If you pay attention, SARS-CoV also have protein similar to Vero protein with $\pu{50 kD}$ (just below SARS-N protein). However, authors didn't mark it meaning they are not interested (I keep telling authors because I assume the image is from a publication).

Comment: Okay, so I believe the image analysis part is that I need to identify all the little lines since I need to consider the total of its protein. Thank you very much.

Comment: @JKalle it is still surprising that the exercise has been given. How one can analyse an image of that type in relation to protein size (obscure in a way in itself, it is number of amino acids or the physical V) without knowing about proteins and the technique used? Really puzzling. Unless you arbitrary resume the actual quiz text.

Comment: @Alchimista, yes and it is frustrating to be given such a task when the image analysis part is not that difficult once I know what he wants me to do. But maybe the teacher thinks that a Western blot is second nature to anyone in science, which is not the case. 
The task does say the 'approximate' size of the S protein relative to the total of the proteins, but that would be implicit either way since it is impossible to determine the exact value from that image.